# Testing Promise.then with Jasmine 2

Tags: javascript, jasmine, promise, karma-jasmine, es6-promise

I have a function that is using a promise and calls another function when that promise fulfills. I'm trying to spy the function that executed in promise.then, however I can't get the expected calls.count() and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
var MyClass = function() {};

MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function(id) {
    var promise = this.check(id);

    promise.then(function(result) {
        this.make();
    });

    return promise;
};

MyClass.prototype.make = function() {};

describe('when', function() {
    var myClass;

    beforeAll(function() {
        myClass = new MyClass();
    });

    it('should', function(done) {
        spyOn(myClass, 'check').and.callFake(function() {
            return Promise.resolve();
        });

        spyOn(myClass, 'make');

        myClass.doSomething(11)
            .then(function() {
                expect(myClass.make.calls.count()).toEqual(1); // says it is called 0 times
                expect(myClass.check.calls.count()).toEqual(1); // says it is called 2 times
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this NodeJS code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your promise is compilant with the A+ spec then this:

```
promise.then(function(result) {
    this.make();
});
```

Will not work. As the spec requires `this` to have no value.

> 2.2.5 onFulfilled and onRejected must be called as functions (i.e. with no this value). [3.2]

[Promises A+ 2.2.5](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-35)

You'll need to do:

```
var that = this;
promise.then(function(result) {
    that.make();
});
```

Also, realize that the returned promise will try to `fulfill` or `reject` other queued promises at the same time as the promise returned by `promise.then(..)` unless you do:

```
promise = promise.then(..)
```

Comment: Thanks you! Would you know why myClass.check.calls.count() is equal to 2 instead of 1? Interesting is when I move that assert statement outside of then it returns 1 as expected.

Comment: `doSomething` calls `check`. So it makes sense that you get an extra count by the time the `then` handler is being called. I don't know why it's being called before. Maybe the `fakeCalll`? I'm not familiar with the test framework.

Answer (score 0):

You have to respect the Promise chain by returning a promise in a promise

```js
var that = this; // according to MinusFour answer
promise.then(function(result) {
   return that.make();
});

return promise;
```